# How to extract all video thumbnails from a playlist using youtube api in android?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, clone, android-youtube-api

Lets take the example below.

Here i can see the Thumbnail of the youTubeThumbnailView1 in the imageView.

I have included some questions as part of comments in the code.

Early on i thought i could just create an ArrayList of ImageView and get all the Thumbnails inside that but that wouldn't work as i can't even access the imageView outside of the method.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    //private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeThumbnailView1);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

            //Accessing imageView here would give NullPointerException
        }

    @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

        //this.youTubeThumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader; for calling next() etc. in onThumbnailLoader(,)

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailListener());
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setPlaylist("ECAE6B03CA849AD332",1);

        //How to call release() on the youTubeThumbnailLoader parameter as it causes ServiceConnectionLeaked after exiting the app. But if you call it here nothing works.
        }

    @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    }

    private class ThumbnailListener implements YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener{

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(youTubeThumbnailView.getDrawable());

            /*How can i access this imageView outside of this method?
              Using something like below will show all the thumbnails BUT how do you access them outside of this method?

            if (youTubeThumbnailLoader.hasNext()) {
               youTubeThumbnailLoader.next();
            } else {
              youTubeThumbnailLoader.first();
            }
            */

            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i recently managed to do this with the help of a library called picasso to load the images into the imageview and android async http to retrieve the list of thumbnails.
Add this to you app-level build.gradle file under dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

For retrieving the images, i made a http get request to the Youtube data API and retrieved all the image URLs and added it as the thumbnail property of the Video class.
More information here on retrieving all the thumbnail: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

I did it like this.

```
 private void loadVideos(String id) {
    //just a method to check if i am connected to the internet
    checkConnected();
    String requestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems";
    String key = API_KEY;
    String param = "?part=id, snippet&playlistId=" + id + "&key=" + key + "&maxResults=50";
    String request = requestUrl + param;

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    client.get(request, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            try {
                videoArr = new ArrayList<Video>();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray playlistItems = obj.getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < playlistItems.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject snippet = playlistItems.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet");
                    String title = snippet.getString("title");
                    String description = snippet.getString("description");

                    JSONObject thumbnailObj = snippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                    //Here i am extracting the URL of the thumbnail
                    String thumbnail = thumbnailObj.getJSONObject("high").getString("url");

                    JSONObject resourceId = snippet.getJSONObject("resourceId");
                    String id = resourceId.getString("videoId");

                    Video video = new Video(id, title, description, thumbnail);
                    videoArr.add(video);
                }
                populateListView(videoArr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

my Video class is as follows:

```
public class Video implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String thumbnail;

    public Video(String id, String title, String description, String thumbnail) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }
}
```

And finally, to load the images, i did it like this using picasso.

```
ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);

//video is my Video object.
Picasso.with(yourActivity.this).load(video.getThumbnail()).fit().into(yourImageView);
```

And don't forget you do have to get an API key from the developers console.Hope i helped. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Thank-you for the reply i will definitely try out your method. But i am curious to know if getting those thumbnails is possible without having to deal with JSON and HTTP explicitly and by only using the youtube-android-api provided by youtube.

Comment: it only gives first 50 results, how to use next page token to get next 50 videos?